# nuxt friendly-errors export 'someModule' was not found in 'somePath'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I've got this warning during coding.

```
 WARN  in ./components/common/tg-file-upload.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

  export 'FileNameReg' was not found in '@/utils/regexp'.       friendly-errors 18:50:04
```

This tip is good.

But I always ignore it.

What should I do if I want the waring uplevel to error

Comment: What do you have in `@/utils/regexp`?